# Избавиться от "пустых" тайлов от kosmosnimki.ru в Layer.OSM

Tags: javascript, openlayers, tile, тайл

Забираю с *kosmosnimki.ru* растровые слои. Специфика сервера *kosmosnimki.ru* в том что тайлы за пределами области растра он не отдаёт.
Пытался решить эту проблему заменяя запрос тайлов у сервера заранее подготовленным пустым прозрачным изображением. Для чего немного модифицировал OpenLayers.Layer.OSM следующим образом:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.OSMKosmosnimki = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, {
    name: "Kosmosnimki",
    url: [
        "http://maps.kosmosnimki.ru/TileService.ashx/map${mapkey}/apikey${apikey}?"
            + "Request=GetTile&LayerName=${layerkey}&x=${x}&y=${y}&z=${z}"
    ],
    attribution: "<a href=\"http://kosmosnimki.ru/\">kosmosnimki.ru</a>",
    isBaseLayer: false,
    apikey: null,
    mapkey: null,
    layerkey: null,
    extent: null,
    getURL: function (bounds) {
        var res = this.getServerResolution();
        var onXYZ = !this.extent
            || (
                (
                    (this.extent.left >= bounds.left  
                        && (this.extent.right <= bounds.right  
                            || (this.extent.left <= bounds.right  
                                && this.extent.right >= bounds.right)))
                    ||
                    (this.extent.right <= bounds.right  
                        && (this.extent.left >= bounds.left  
                            || (this.extent.right >= bounds.left  
                                && this.extent.left <= bounds.left)))
                    ||
                    (this.extent.left < bounds.left  
                        && this.extent.right > bounds.right)
                )
                &&
                (
                    (this.extent.bottom >= bounds.bottom  
                        && (this.extent.top <= bounds.top  
                            || (this.extent.bottom <= bounds.top  
                                && this.extent.top >= bounds.top)))
                    ||
                    (this.extent.top <= bounds.top  
                        && (this.extent.bottom >= bounds.bottom  
                            || (this.extent.top >= bounds.bottom  
                                && this.extent.bottom <= bounds.bottom)))
                    ||
                    (this.extent.top > bounds.top 
                        && this.extent.bottom < bounds.bottom)
                )
               );
        if (onXYZ) {
            var x = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / 
                                                           (res * this.tileSize.w));
            var y = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / 
                                                           (res * this.tileSize.h));
            var z = this.getServerZoom();

            if (this.wrapDateLine) {
                var limit = Math.pow(2, z);
                x = ((x % limit) + limit) % limit;
            };

            var xyz = {
                'mapkey': this.mapkey,
                'apikey': this.apikey,
                'layerkey': this.layerkey,
                'x': x,
                'y': y,
                'z': z
            };
            var url = this.url;
            if (OpenLayers.Util.isArray(url)) {
                var s = '' + xyz.x + xyz.y + xyz.z;
                url = this.selectUrl(s, url);
            };
            return OpenLayers.String.format(url, xyz);
        } else {
            return "/images/tile404.png"
        };
    },
    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Layer.OSMKosmosnimki"
});
```

Этот код прекрасно работает, если растр прямоугольный, то есть не повернут вообще!
Если же отдаваемый *kosmosnimki.ru* растр немного повернут, то при увеличении найдутся масштабы в которых есть растры покрывающие расчитанную прямоугольную область, но при этом не содержащие фрагментов растра! Почему то и эти тайлы сервер *kosmosnimki.ru* не отдаёт!
Если сервер *kosmosnimki.ru* не отдает растр, то в консоли выдается ошибка

```
GET http://maps.kosmosnimki.ru/TileService.ashx/ ....... 404 (Not Found)
```

В связи с этим **вопрос**:
как отловить эту ошибку в конкретном слое и заменить ссылку на тайл, который вызвал ошибку, ссылкой на заранее подготовленное изображение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашлось решение:

[How to avoid Pink tiles when DB view/Table is empty?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/how-to-avoid-pink-tiles-when-db-view-table-is-empty)

Answer (score 1):

Отслеживайте заголовки ответа сервера. Это наиболее правильный вариант, я полагаю.

Comment: Другими словами вы хотите сказать, что в *OpenLayers* нет штатных средств отлова ошибок загрузки тайлов ?  
И, как я понимаю, нужно влезать в **OpenLayers.Tile.Image** (предполагаю метод **renderTile**) ?